# How to hide the jelly attribute

Tags: jenkins, jelly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOCRS.png)
I want to hide this label. What should I do? If anyone knows, I would greatly appreciate it

I tried to add the id attribute and use getElementsById to obtain this tag, but it was found to be null

Comment: <f:entry title="name" field="name">
        ...
</f:entry>I want to hide this label

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.